# swiper несколько pagination в одном container

Tags: jquery, api, swiper

подскажите, как сделать два и более pagination в одном слайдере

```
 var slider2 = new Swiper (".slider2", {
  // Optional parameters
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "bullets",
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction",
  }
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе с сохранением роботоспобности элементов навигации, то можешь просто динамически с клонировать нужные тебе элементы

```
$(".swiper-pagination").clone('true').addClass("newPagination").appendTo('body');
```

Как-то так. Ну а потом поставить куда надо, и стилизировать отталкиваясь от нового класса.